# How much CO2 is currently captured in the EU per year with CCS technologies?

Tags: carbon-sequestration

I wonder how much carbon dioxide is captured per annum in the EU at the moment. In this [article](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/info/files/iogp_-_report_-_ccs_ccu.pdf) (p. 5), one can read that the two largest CCS facilities in Europe currently capture around 1,55 Mt/y. However, there are many other smaller CCS facilities deployed throughout Europe. I'd like to how know much carbon dioxide they capture each year in total.

Comment: I spent a while looking for this data and as best I can tell, it just isn't out there. The IEA [gives an estimate of 35 million tons globally in 2019](https://www.iea.org/fuels-and-technologies/carbon-capture-utilisation-and-storage), but they don't provide context or a source. There's also a Global CCS Institute that has [an annual report](https://www.globalccsinstitute.com/resources/global-status-report/) and a [database of facilities](https://co2re.co/), but both of these seem to prioritize flashy graphics over detailed statistics.